# SQL DATABASE ENGINE permisions

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I want to deny query for insert,update,delete,alter in database engine only? is there a way to do that ? Because I have an application that uses the SQL database server and has a lot of users that consists of a lot of levels. I use the connection to the database with ADODB. How do I only can execute insert, update, delete or procedure only on the application, but can not run in SQL server database engine?

example: users A can insert,delete or update data into 'customer' through application, but cannot execute query that contain insert,delete, or update from database engine. because is too risky if users do that and can manipulate data from there.

Thanks Before

Comment: You want to prevent users executing direct queries and allow access only through application? Is the application running on users' workstation or on a (web) server?

Comment: @vonPryz the applicaton running on users' workstation

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve by limiting access? Is this about security? Data integrity? Something else?

Comment: it's about security, so users cannot executing direct queries and must from application. do you have a idea @vonPryz

Comment: It would be **much** easier to help you if you'd edit the post and add more details. Please explain what's going on and *what* kind of behavior you want to prevent and *why*.

Comment: For example: "prevent user entering broken data about a customer" is very different a problem from "prevent user entering data for a customer that is managed by another an user".

Comment: @vonPryz i want to prevent users manipulate data like transaction detail or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the application is running on user workstation, it is likely to be run on user's own account. This, unfortunately, means you are out of luck with the simple solution - setting up user permissions.

What *could* work is an approach based on stored procedures with [`EXECUTE AS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx).

There are lots of [tutorials](http://dataeducation.com/blog/basic-impersonation-using-execute-as) in the net. For a summary:

1. Create a user account for application usage and grant it appropriate rights to the database objects.
2. Create stored procedures to handle all the required data operations. Use
   `EXECUTE AS` to run those procedures as the application user.
3. Grant your users rights to execute the procedures.
4. Revoke other permissions from the users.